# Fail to separate sound signals by FastICA on real-world recording

Tags: python, signal-processing, audio-recording, recording

I have written a program to perform FastICA on a stereo WAV file using the code on [Python MDP FastICA Example](http://www.endolith.com/wordpress/2009/11/22/a-simple-fastica-example/)

With the audio examples I get very good results.

Then I try to do real world recording using two computer mono microphones connected to the stereo mic in of my pc by connecting mic 1 to L channel and mic 2 to R channel. I test by playing some music at the background while I am talking in a quiet room.

However, running FastICA does not separate the signals at all. Is it possible that the quality of microphones is too poor? Do I need to do anything to the recorded WAV file before running FastICA?

Comment: This is more of a DSP question than a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Please refer to http://inc2.ucsd.edu/~taesu/ to find matlab code for sound separation in real recording. It is easy to use and works very nice.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ready yet for real-live recording.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot help you but just share my experiences since I tried some time ago to get ICA separating sources in real world audio conditions...

With normal [A-B stereo technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereophonic_sound#A-B_technique:_time-of-arrival_stereophony) it is quite clear why ICA is not able to separate the sources: Because both channels have different delays of sources. Especially for this a colleague and me made recordings with a [X-Y setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereophonic_sound#X-Y_technique:_intensity_stereophony) because then both channels should have the same delays. We even did it outdoor to reduce the effect of delayed sound reflections from the walls. But ICA has not been able to separate the sources...